# Check if text from ComboBox is the same has other ComboBox

Tags: qt, qcombobox

I have 8 ComboBoxes with the tag as channel_1 ... channel_8.

I want to check if the user chooses the same option in 2 of them, except the first option which is 'none'.

I've created this slot but the `final_a` and `final_b` variables created are not recognized.

```
// Slot to check if there's two channels with the same option choosed
void gui::check_channels_options()
{
    for (int a = 1; a <= 8; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 1; b <= 8; b++)
        {
            if(a != b)
            {
                QString A, B;
                A.setNum(a);
                B.setNum(b);

                QString Na, Nb;
                Na = "channel_";
                Na += A;
                Nb = "channel_";
                Nb += B;

                QByteArray bytes_a = Na.toAscii();
                char* final_a = bytes_a.data();

                QByteArray bytes_b = Nb.toAscii();
                char* final_b = bytes_b.data();

                if((ui->final_a->currentText() == ui->final_b->currentText()) &&
                        (ui->final_a->currentIndex() != 0 && ui->fnal_b->currentIndex() != 0))
                {
                    QMessageBox::warning(this,"Error","Channel " + a + " has the same option as channel " + b,QMessageBox::Ok);
                }

                else
                {

                }
            }     
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `final_a` and `final_b` on the stack, but then referring to them as `ui->final_a` and `ui->final_b`. Try removing the "`ui->`" from those.

In general, I think your approach could be simplified, though. For example, say you have pointers to your combo boxes stored in an array called `comboBoxes`. Then you can just do this:

```
// create the combo boxes somewhere in your program, perhaps like this:
QComboBox *comboBoxes[8];
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
    comboBoxes[i] = new QComboBox;
}

// Slot to check if there's two channels with the same option choosed
void gui::check_channels_options()
{
    for (int a = 0; a < 8; ++a)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < 8; ++b)
        {
            if (a == b ||
                comboBoxes[a]->currentText() == "none" ||
                comboBoxes[b]->currentText() == "none")
                continue; // no need to test these for equality
            else if (comboBoxes[a]->currentText() == comboBoxes[b]->currentText)
                // issue warning
            else
                // they are OK
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I created a `QComboBox combobox[8];`, `combobox[0] = ui->channel_1;` ... till channel_8. and I get `error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'QComboBox'`

Comment: Close... You created eight combo boxes on the stack. Instead, you want pointers to combo boxes. For example: `QComboBox *comboBoxes[8];` Once you do that, you can just iterate through them like this `for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {comboBoxes[i] = new QComboBox;}`. Or, if the combo boxes are created elsewhere in the program, you could just do `comboBoxes[0] = someComboBox; comboBoxes[1] = someOtherComboBox;`, etc. See edit to my code above.

Comment: so, If I understood it correctly instead of `QComboBox comboBoxes[8]` just create a  `QComboBox comboBoxes`

Comment: Then you can do something like this: `QComboBox *comboBoxes[8];` `comboBoxes[0] = ui->someComboBox;`. `comboBoxes[1] = ui->someOtherComboBox;`, etc. No need to create them again, you just want the pointers to point to something.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23910/discussion-between-samuelnlp-and-anthony)

Answer (score 0):

ui->final_a->currentText(), i dont think you can access the UI elem ent this way. there is no *final_a* element in UI, but there'd be some channel_1, channel2, element as i understood.

ps: please give variables a meaningful name,